# Commit differences missing / conflict related?

Tags: git

Members of my team recently reported changes in their code (lines removed) that did not show in any commits, while still being active in the code base. Technically, they had code in a feature branch, but that code then went into the final branch with some lines missing.

Using the normal git commands for searching commits (`git -S 'somexpr' ...`, and even `git log -u` and searching the output), I was able to find where the lines were added. But nowhere in the active branch without the lines could I find those lines later disappearing again.

I'm no git expert, but I've vaguely read something about git not showing merge diffs by default, so I've also experimented with the options `-C` and `--cc`. Without success.

Using `git blame --reverse HASHWHERELINEEXISTS filename` however, I was able to find the hash prefix where the line last appeared. Then using `git log` and manual search, I was able to find the commit in the log. When examining that commit and the one before it individually, I was still not able to get the diff with the lines disappearing though.

This makes me suspect that maybe those lines disappeared as part of conflict resolution, and that these diffs aren't usually shown anywhere.

I think I finally managed to force git to display the actual diff though (including conflict resolution or whatever). The "trick" was basically to execute `git diff HASHFROMREVERSEBLAME..HASBEFORETHATONE` (where those HASH.. values refer to copy paste from the git log output mentioned above).

Which leave the questions:

- Any experts that can explain what's going on, and what the easiest method to locate/search such changes (possibly conflict related) is?
- Assuming I was able to locate the correct diff finally, surely git must have some way of searching through such differences? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Your diagnosis here is correct:

> I've vaguely read something about git not showing merge diffs by default ...

Specifically, `git log -p` walks the commit graph (see below), but when it hits a merge, just doesn't bother showing a diff, by default.  What you want is `-m`, possibly combined with `--first-parent`.  See the details below.

> I've also experimented with the options `-C` and `--cc`...

The `-C` option is irrelevant here (it is passed to the diff engine, where it means "find whole-file copies", which has other uses but isn't any good for your problem).  The `-c` (lowercase) and `--cc` (two dashes and two lowercase `c` letters) options are relevant, but not helpful, as we'll see below.

#### What to know about the commits themselves

In Git, each commit:

- contains a snapshot of all the files Git knows about, in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format;
- contains some metadata: information about the commit itself; and
- is numbered, by the commit's *hash ID*, which looks random (it isn't but there's no easy way to *predict* them and they're not ordered).

Git looks up these things (commits, and other internal Git objects) by their hash-ID numbers, so you need to provide the commit number to Git to get it to do anything useful.  Commit numbers, however, are not useful to *humans*.  So we generally don't use them—well, except in special cases, with cut-and-paste for instance.  Instead, we use *names*.  In particular we tend to use *branch names* like `master` and *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master`.  A branch name identifies one specific commit, by holding that commit's number.

The special feature of a branch name is that it always holds the hash ID of the *last* commit on that branch.  That might not seem all that useful—what good is it to know the hash ID of the *last* commit, without knowing the hash IDs of earlier commits?—until we mention that, in its metadata, each commit stores the commit number of the *previous* commit.  Git calls this the *parent* of the commit.

What this means is that we can draw the commits, with earlier ones towards the left and later ones towards the right, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, each uppercase letter stands in for some random-looking hash ID.  `H` in particular stands in for the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Once we can find commit `H`, we can use commit `H`'s metadata, which contains the hash ID of commit `G`, to have Git find commit `G`.  Commit `G` in turn stores the hash ID of earlier commit `F` in *its* metadata, so from `G`, we can move back to earlier commit `F`, and so on.  All we need is the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain—and that's exactly what a branch name holds.

Hence, we can draw this a little more simply as:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

The branch name `master` gives us the hash ID so that Git can find commit `H`.  We omit the arrows between commits because we know that once a new commit is made, nothing inside it can ever change—not any of the files, nor any of the metadata—and that Git works *backwards*, from child to parent, to find commits.

To make a *new* commit, Git will:

- write out the files (in the special read-only de-duplicated Git format);
- write out the appropriate metadata, including the name and email address of whoever is making the commit, and "now" as the date-and-time-stamps—and in this case, `H`'s hash ID as the (single) parent of the new commit—to give us:

  ```
   ...--F--G--H   <-- master
               \
                I
  ```
- finally, now that commit `I` exists—the creation of the commit assigns it its new unique hash ID—`git commit` will make the *name* `master` hold its new hash ID:

  ```
   ...--F--G--H
               \
                I   <-- master
  ```

There's no reason to keep the kink in the drawing; we could now just write:

```
...--H--I   <-- master
```

#### How `git log` shows you commits

Skipping over a bunch of important details, one of which we'll touch on in a moment, what `git log` does is to walk backwards through the commits.  By starting from a name like `master`, we—or Git anyway—can find the latest commit, such as commit `I`.  This has a full snapshot of every file that Git knew about when we made commit `I`.

Next, Git steps back one commit, to `H`.  This of course also has a full snapshot of every file.  So Git essentially extracts both commits, and compares all the files in the two commits.  This is a form of `git diff`, as run by `git log -p`: *compare any two commits*.  Here, the two commits are `I` (the current one in the walk) and `H` (its parent).

For files that are the same, the diff code does nothing at all.  There's nothing to say about these files.  For files that are different, the diff code comes up with some set of changes that would change the left-side (`H`) commit copy into the right-side (`I`) commit copy.  That's the diff that you see.  (For all-new files, or files that got deleted, you see an appropriate recipe here as well.  The `-C` option tells Git: *If a right-side file is all-new, see if it's actually wholly or partly copied from some existing file in the left-side commit.*)

This is fine for these ordinary, simple, single-parent commits, but it doesn't work for merges.

#### Merge commits are slightly different

When you use `git merge` to make a real merge, the merge commit:

- holds a snapshot, as usual; and
- has metadata, as usual, *except*
- in the metadata, the merge commit holds *more than one* previous-commit number.

It's this last fact, which is really pretty simple, that makes a commit a merge commit.

We can draw a merge commit like this:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M   <-- branch
         /
...--K--L
```

This merge commit has two parents.  Most merge commits look like this, although Git also supports what they call an *octopus merge*, where there are three or more parents.

When we hit a merge commit in the commit-walking process, `git log` has to get more complicated.  What it does by default is to walk *both legs* of the incoming commits, in some order, going from `M` back to `L`, but also going from `M` back to `J`.  You can use the `--first-parent` flag to tell the graph-walking code to look only at the *numerically first* parent, which in Git, is the commit from the branch you were on at the time you ran `git merge`.  (The other parent, or parents for an octopus merge, are the other commit or commits that you merged.)

But the `git diff` code has a problem.  You can't really diff the merge commit's snapshot against either parent and get something sensible.  At the same time, you can't diff the merge commit against all the parents at the same time ... unless—well, here things get a bit squirrelly.

For `git log` itself, its solution is *don't bother showing a diff at all*.  Unfortunately this solution completely hides an incorrect merge, which is why you can't find the bad merge this way.

For `git show`, which shows one commit's log message and a patch, the default solution is to use `--cc` mode, which leads us to the somewhat peculiar definition of a *combined diff* in Git.  The `-c` option also produces a combined diff, with a slightly different combination method.  But both of these are useless for your particular problem because of one special feature of a combined diff.

#### Git's combine diff omits some files entirely

When Git produces a combined diff, what it does is:

- For each parent of the merge-commit child, do a quick diff to find identical files and different files.  (Because of the internal storage format, with de-duplication of files, this part is very fast.)
- For any file that's *entirely the same* in the child as *any* parent's copy of that same file, don't say anything at all.
- For every file in the child that's different from that same file in *every* parent, run a diff against each parent.  Then show parts of that diff.  (Precisely which parts you see depend on whether you used `-c` or `--cc`, but they're both pretty similar.)

Since your case involves someone who accidentally made the merge commit use exactly the same file as one of its parents, instead of taking changes from *both* parents, a combined diff will, by definition, skip right over that file.  So that's what makes combined diffs useless here.

#### The `-m` option

The `-m` option—which is available for both `git log` *and* `git show`—tells Git to pretend, just for diffing purposes, that one *merge commit* is N separate commits, where N is the number of parents.  That is, given:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M   <-- branch
         /
...--K--L
```

the `git log` command will still cover `M`, go back to `J`, and then from `J to` I`, and so on; and will still also cover` L`, and` K`, and so on, as needed, in some order.  But while showing` M` itself, Git will pretend that there exist two separate commits that look like this:

```
J--M1

L--M2
```

and therefore run *two* `git diff` commands, one that compare the snapshot in `J` to the snapshot in `M1`, and the other that compares the snapshot in `J` to that in `M2` (with the two "M" snapshots both *really* being the snapshot in `M` itself, of course).

In one of these two diffs, the file you care about will not be changed at all.  In the other, you'll see that some line that *should* be carried through—say from `L` to `M2`—was changed to match the line in `J` instead.  That shows you the bad commit, and who made it.

#### Why a lot of this doesn't really matter

Except for educating whoever made the bad commit, the only thing you *can* do at this point is to make a new commit that has the file corrected.<sup>1</sup>  It doesn't matter who makes this corrected commit.  All of the previous commits literally cannot be changed.  So just make a fix, commit it, and move on.

#### History rewriting

If you like, you can do what people call "history rewriting".  Here we take a series of commits:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M--N--O--P   <-- branch
         /
...--K--L
```

where there is some problem, say at `M`, and make a series of new commits:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M'-N'-O'-P'   <-- replacement-branch
         /
...--K--L
```

The old commits continue to exist, but since we find them by *name*, all we have to do now is get everyone to swap the name `replacement-branch` for the name `branch`, and vice versa.  Then the *old* (bad) commits will be found under the new name, and the new (good) commits will be found under the old name.

The problem with history rewriting is that we have to convince *everyone with a clone* of the *bad* repository to change *their* branch names.  While *commits* get shared—you connect one Git to another and the Git that doesn't have some commits will, in general, get those commits from the other one—every copy of a Git repository has *its own* private branch names.  So everyone who is using the "wrong" branch has to update *their* private branch name so that it uses the new and improved commits.  It's easy to *get* those commits, but the default will be to *merge the new and improved commits with the old bad ones*, which is just what you don't want.

Still, if there's not that much history, and few clones that have the bad commits, the history rewrite trick can be a good option.  It's not trivial when there are merges involved, though—and not worth trying to write up here (there are other StackOverflow answers covering this sort of thing).

Comment: Thank you for a thorough explanation. I'm still not sure I get it though, other than that it is very hard to find, and can't be found without manual work. A normal `git log -u` will show the line being added, but not removed as described. When looking at commits individually, it can not be found. But when I look at `git diff` between two consecutive commits  from where the first one has the missing code (WITH) and the second one does not (WITHOUT), it does actually show the commit. But this probably doesn't tell me exactly how that code got removed, only when it got merged into the branch.

Comment: Assuming this is normal behaviour, I guess a script that walks a branch commit by commit and doing a diff that could be searched would at least be very useful to identify WHEN some code disappeared. It doesn't necessarily answer the WHO part as that code could have changed long before the merge commit. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `git log -m` with `-S` or `-G` will find the merge that dropped the line you care about, but it will still take a fair bit of manual work *unless* `--first-parent` happens to also find it (you'll need both `-m` and `--first-parent` here). If the combined flags find it quickly, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`git log -S <pattern>` will not display a commit where the pattern is "moved" from one file to another.

If you have an identified file or directory where this line has disappeared, you can look in the changes that target only this file :

```
git log -S <pattern> -- this/file
git log -S <pattern> -- this/directory
```

the computations of `-S` will now be limited to the diffs that affected `this/file` or `this/directory`, instead of the diff of the complete repo ;

or use `-G <pattern>`, which will show diffs where the pattern *appears*, even if its count didn't change.

Comment: Neither of those commands for that file shows anything related to the line that went missing, but the diff between the two consecutive commits does however, That's the puzzling part. As mentioned, the relevant diff doesn't appear in any of the two commits involved (which I assume git "searches" for), but it does appear when I tell git to show the diff between the two hashes directly.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitattributes` file in your repo ? which would possibly define some filters to run on your files ?

Comment: No .gitattributes. When testing with just `git log -uG <pattern>`, the commit adding the lines show up. But not where they were later removed.

Comment: Weird. You mention a commit where the line disappears : it is a regular commit, correct ? not a merge commit ?

Comment: If merge commits are involved, try the `-m` option : it should show you the two diffs of a merge commit with each of its parent commit.

Comment: The `-m` option shows the line yes! But it shows it as being added, not removed. So could it be that if it was a conflict or something, it got removed there? And maybe there's some ordering issue when doing the diff from the individual commits (that it really got removed, but it's showing the two branches the "wrong" way, if there IS a right way, not sure)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220001/discussion-between-legec-and-marius-kjeldahl).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody that tried to help. I further diagnosed this today, and things are looking better.

In short, the magic command is:

`git log -u -m -S searchexpr`

The `-u` is for showing the diffs, the `-m` is to include "merge diffs". After some regular work and pulling various branches again, this command now seems to include everything as expected.

Without the `-m`, it only shows the line being added in the first place. With the `-m` it also shows the line being removed in a later merge.

I had a colleague of mine test the first command on his copy of the branch on his computer, and he says he does not get any output from that command at all. Sounds like me yesterday. So there seems to be some circumstances where git aren't finding our commits properly. When/if I figure out why I will share.

Update: I also checked with some of the other team members, and there was actually some differences in the branch history on the same branch, which may have added to the confusion. I suspect somebody reset the branch at one time and force pushed it upstream, but not everybody on the team picked up the fact that they should reset to upstream. So people have been doing conflict resolution and probably messed it up somewhat. Live and learn, we're already working on better branching strategies and procedures for commits and MRs.